# How to denied all requests except some in Magento

Tags: magento

The question is not enough clear, so I will explain more.

My client has a requirement in ***`mobile`***<sup>1</sup> about the users all SHOULD not visit all `request`<sup>2</sup>

#### For example:

The users **SHOULD:** only visit some in below list:

- mydomain.com/catalog/product/view
- mydomain.com/cusotmer/account/`any_action`
- mydomain.com/onepage/checkout/`any_action`

So, I am having a solution is at the method: **`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()`**
I will get the `request` variable to check what is `moulde`, `controller`, `action`. If it is valid in list, if not I will redirect to an accessed denied page.

I know that is bad, so I am looking for other solutions.

---

> **1:** We've already designed a theme for mobile, just want to give for user some pages are necessary.
> **2:** I mean to the router format: **module**/ **controller**/ **action**.

---

#### UPDATE:

Thanks all guys so much. Now, I understand what I need to do. I don't know how to close my question. So please help me if you can. I don't want to be a member who never accept the answer.

Comment: Why do you think it's bad solution? Magento EE uses the same approach to restrict access to the website.

Comment: So, if I don't wanna edit in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class, there is exist another way to do, using `observer` or `override` this class? I just try to ask for your advice? I am a novice.

Comment: @vietan: [IMHO](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IMHO)

Comment: I believe there is a Mage::dispatch in the preDispatch() method so just hook into that event and do your thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not good question which could be easy to answer, but very happy for help from [@azakolyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861479/azakolyukin) and [@elgabbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295654/elgabbu)

So, I think [@azakolyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861479/azakolyukin)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595822/how-to-denied-all-requests-except-some-in-magento#comment-9214572) is correct answer.